# C# PowerPoint VSTO UndoRecord like in Word

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop

Microsoft Word has the concept of an [UndoRecord](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh420330.aspx) which allows you to start and end a custom `UndoRecord`.

Unfortunately, it does not look like PowerPoint's [Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745704.aspx) object has the same property.

**Question**: how can you manage the undo/redo state in a PowerPoint VSTO application?

The use case is that I am performing a number of steps within the slide, which I want to bundle into one undo/redo step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerPoint, you have _Application.StartNewUndoEntry

[link to msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Application.StartNewUndoEntry);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true)

Just call the method every time you want to add an entry in the undo stack. You have no control over the name of the entry, or anything else for that matter...

Comment: Okay - so, there is no way to remove items from the undo stack then? I'll give this a try and then report back.

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick. Shame the API doesn't allow for editing the whole record stack.